# plsql ora -00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a package (DATA_PKG) which contains functions to return a row of data when given a primary key value. I have found a situation where one of the DATA_PKG functions fails when called by a procedure in another package (CALLER_PKG). It throws up the following error:

```
ora -00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
```

When I compile CALLER with the exact same function in the package body it works.  Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "DATA_PKG" AS

  FUNCTION data_function
   (primary_i IN table_name.id%type)
   RETURN table_name%ROWTYPE;

END DATA_PKG;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "DATA_PKG" AS

  FUNCTION data_function
   (primary_i IN table_name.id%type)
   RETURN table_name%ROWTYPE AS
   retval table_name%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO retval FROM table_name WHERE id = primary_i;

    RETURN retval;
  END data_function;

END DATA_PKG;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "CALLER" AS

  PROCEDURE calling_proc
   (key_i IN table_name.id%TYPE);

END CALLER;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "CALLER" AS

  PROCEDURE calling_proc
   (key_i IN table_name.id%TYPE) AS
   table_rec table_name%rowtype;
  BEGIN
   table_rec := data_pkg.data_function(primary_i=>key_i);
   /*
     do something with the returned record
   */
  END calling_proc;

END CALLER;
```

When caller.calling_proc is executed this code fails with ora -00932 in the way described above.

The following code works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "CALLER" AS

  FUNCTION data_function
   (primary_i IN table_name.id%type)
   RETURN table_name%ROWTYPE AS
   retval table_name%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO retval FROM table_name WHERE id = primary_i;

    RETURN retval;
  END data_function;

  PROCEDURE calling_proc
   (key_i IN table_name.id%TYPE) AS
   table_rec table_name%rowtype;
  BEGIN
   table_rec := data_function(primary_i=>key_i);
   /*
     do something with the returned record
   */
  END calling_proc;

END CALLER;
```

Can anyone tell me why this works with, what I consider to be, a trivial change to the code?  The error suggests that the datatypes are inconsistent but I haven't changed any in my 'solution'.

Has this happened to anyone before?  Also can anyone explain what the dashes in the error message represent?  I would expect to see a datatype named here.

Comment: `expected - got -` did you remove the actual types with `-`?

Comment: I have reproduced the error message literally.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this, on 11g XE 11.2.0.2.0.  Your first block of code completes successfully.  Would it be possible to add your table definitions on the off-chance it's related to the types of column in your table?  Also, is it possible to show the full stack trace of the error?  As for the meaning of the dashes, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4592319).

Comment: I am guessing the `/*do something with the returned record*/` in the `calling_proc` does datatype incompatible operations that causes the error. Otherwise I don't see any issues and I implemented the above packages and they all work well.

Comment: Annjawn:  sorry but I just left a comment there because it is irrelevant.  The error happens prior to that.

Comment: Luke: yes, I saw that question but it didn't help me.  I don't really want to post the table definition but the primary key is of the datatype NUMBER.  The question you linked to is relevant in one respect.  That is that the procedure is being called by a PHP script.  This script passes an array as a collection.  The procedure which the PHP script calls accepts one parameter which is of the type table of varchar2(30000).  I am not sure why that should make a difference though.

Comment: You might the oracle 4000 chars limit using the varchar2 datatype. As you don't post the complete code its difficult to assess. From the oracle documentation: "Oracle provides the ability in both SQL and PL/SQL to work with the VARCHAR2 data type. However, they differ in their maximum allowed length. Within PL/SQL, local variables of type VARCHAR2 can be declared to contain up to 32,767 characters while declaring a database column of type VARCHAR2 can contain up to 4000 characters. This SQL VARCHAR2 limit of 4000 characters exists even when VARCHAR2 values appear inside DML statements."

Comment: Are both packages owned by the same schema?  Is the table in question owned by the same schema as the packages?  Is the user executing the packages the one who owns them?

Comment: Because, as you say, this is a puzzling occurrence.  So there must be some difference in teh set-up which you haven't told us.

Comment: APC: Yes, all are owned by the same schema and all are executed by the user who owns them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
table_rec := data_pkg.data_function(primary_i=>key_i);
```

Try this (may work, though both of them are literally same)

```
SELECT data_pkg.data_function(primary_i=>key_i)
  INTO table_rec
  FROM dual;
```